# Ubuntu erase disk and install option is not removing previous partitions

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi, lvm

I have a new computer Asus motherboard, and WD Blue 1TB SSD. Secure Boot set to Other OS (off). Due to problems with Nvidia drivers, I tried to reinstall Ubuntu Budgie 20.04. My first installation was an encrypted LVM.

When I clicked the option to erase disk and install, for some reason instead of deleting all partitions in the previous installation, the new install created sub-partitions inside the previous root partition.

List of partitions in `/dev/nvme0n1`:

```
free space                        1 MB
/dev/nvme0n1p1       efi        536 MB
/dev/nvme0n1p2      ext4        767 MB
/dev/nvme0n1p3    unknown    998898 MB
free space                        0 MB
```

Then, in a live session I manually deleted all the partitions using GParted, and then reinstalled. Now I’m getting a message:

> system problem detected report

And booting into recovery mode, I get this error message:

> Cannot process volume group vgubuntu-budgie
> Volume group vgubuntu-budgie not found.
> Cannot process volume group vgubuntu-budgie

I've reinstalled Ubuntu many times on other systems and haven't seen this happen before.

My questions are:

1. Shouldn’t the erase disk and install Ubuntu option wipe out previous installations on the SSD? So why do I need to manually delete partitions/format disk?
2. How can I cleanly install Ubuntu without any previous installs lingering in the UEFI?

Comment: Why don't you run a live session from installation media (Try Ubuntu).  You can use the "Disks" application to format (erase) your hard drive(s) prior to beginning the installation

Comment: Thank you for reply, to install Ubuntu I ran a live session from usb (Try Ubuntu) and formatted disk using Gparted

Comment: Try "Disks" instead and **format** the disk instead of just deleting partitions. If you are using a different flavor than Ubuntu Desktop and Disks isn't included, you can run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility`

Comment: What should I format disk as? Or can you recommend any tutorials on this? I'm still not sure why, I thought when installing ubuntu it formats disk automatically?

Comment: You do not need to make any partitions or file systems. Just choose GPT since you will be installing a modern operating system. I'm not sure what is the problem that is preventing the installer from formatting the disk but if you can't format using Disks in a live session, it could be a hardware fault

Comment: Just to clarify, is the error message `system problem detected report` or is it actually `System program problem detected`?

Comment: Sorry, error message is `System program problem detected` and I have option to report it, in the desktop environment, not in recovery mode.

Comment: @Nmath will reformatting the disk be safe for the ssd? Also what is the difference between reformatting using gnome-disk-utility and using gparted? I've seen answers here that mention using gparted?

Comment: What do you mean by safe? Formatting will erase everything on the disk but it's not going to damage it.  It doesn't matter whether you use Disks or gparted to format.  When formatting with Disks, it simply creates a partition scheme and marks all space as available.    If the disk is already damaged and can't be formatted, it will probably need to be replaced.